# I am trying to edit table in mysql using java, and i recieve syntax error, but I cannot see where it is

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I just started to learn java, I looked answers in web but nothing seems to work.

There is a syntax error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=1' at
>   line 1    at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1335)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2108)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1245)
>     at DaoImplement.editCar(DaoImplement.java:108)  at
>   Main.main(Main.java:46)

in code:

```
public void editCar(Car editedCar) throws SQLException {
    final String EDIT_CAR = String.format("UPDATE %s SET " +
            "carVin = %d, " +
            "carBrand = '%s', " +
            "carModel = '%s', " +
            "carDateOfProduction = '%s', " +
            "carColour = '%s', ",
            "WHERE id = %d;",
            tableName,
            editedCar.getCarVin(),
            editedCar.getCarBrand(),
            editedCar.getCarModel(),
            editedCar.getCarDateOfProduction(),
            editedCar.getCarColour(),
            editedCar.getId());

    statement.executeUpdate(EDIT_CAR);
    System.out.println("Samochód został nadpisany");
}
```

I don't see where in "WHERE id = %d;" is syntax error.
Someone know how can I fix it? :)

Comment: Remove the comma from this: `"carColour = '%s', "`

Comment: You have an unwanted comma before `WHERE`, that's a syntax error. Also, you should consider using prepared statements.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, remove the comma before `"WHERE"` keyword in the EDIT_CAR String (this is the syntax problem). Secondly, I suggest to modify your method as follow (assuming you db connection is `conn` and that Car attribute `carDateOfProduction` is of type `java.sql.Date`):

```
public void editCar(Car editedCar) throws SQLException {
    final String EDIT_CAR = String.format("UPDATE %s SET "
            + "carVin = ?, "
            + "carBrand = ?, "
            + "carModel = ?, "
            + "carDateOfProduction = ?, "
            + "carColour = ? ",
            "WHERE id = ?",
            tableName);
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(EDIT_CAR);
    stmt.setInt(1, editedCar.getCarVin());
    stmt.setString(2, editedCar.getCarBrand());
    stmt.setString(3, editedCar.getCarModel());
    stmt.setDate(4, editedCar.getCarDateOfProduction());
    stmt.setString(5, editedCar.getCarColour());
    stmt.setInt(1, editedCar.getId());
    stmt.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Samochód został nadpisany");
}
```

PreparedStatement are preferrable over simple Statement, for security reasons. Building a Statement dynamically is vulnerable to SQL injection. Moreover, with PreparedStatement you can avoid syntax errors that arise quoting values in predicates (i.e. "WHERE" clauses).

Comment: carDateOfProduction is a String, main task in this, was to connect to mysql database, and use CRUD options, I will try to rewrite my code as You suggested, thanks!